# nuSOAP - registering a function that does not return anything?

Tags: php, nusoap

I'd like my SOAP server to register a function that does not return anything. I tried passing array() as return list, but it didn't work. How can I do that?

Comment: It is allways wise to return something, even if it is just a 0/1 for success/failure. I think you should reconsider your motives - or do you have a reasonable explanation for not wanting to return anything?

Comment: It was a homework project question anyway.